# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String> while using fromMap constructor in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am creating a basic chat app where it is required to fetch all available chatrooms,

here i am fetching data from firebasefirestore's collection named chatrooms,

my purpose is simple to show all available chatroom of logged user...but i am stuck in the begining while converting..

its showing following error while converting

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>
```

here is my simple chatroommodel

```
class ChatRoomModel {
  String chatroomid;
  List<String> participants;
  ChatRoomModel({required this.chatroomid, required this.participants});

  factory ChatRoomModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ChatRoomModel(
        chatroomid: map['chatroomid'],
        participants:map['participants']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "chatroomid": chatroomid,
      "participants": participants,
    };
  }
}
```

and this is method for fetching data from firebase and convert into object list

```
Future<void> fetchData() async {
    QuerySnapshot qsnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(
        "chatrooms").get();
    final int num_of_rooms = qsnapshot.docs.length;
    print(num_of_rooms);
    if (num_of_rooms > 0) {
      final alldata=qsnapshot.docs.map((e) => e).toList();
      List<ChatRoomModel> templist=[];
      for(var x in alldata)
        {
          templist.add(ChatRoomModel.fromMap(x.data() as Map<String,dynamic>));
        }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your `List<String> participants;` into `List<dynamic> participants;`
like this code :

```
    class ChatRoomModel {
      String chatroomid;
      List<dynamic> participants;
      ChatRoomModel({required this.chatroomid, required this.participants});
    
      factory ChatRoomModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
        return ChatRoomModel(
            chatroomid: map['chatroomid'],
            participants:map['participants']);
      }
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        return {
          "chatroomid": chatroomid,
          "participants": participants,
        };
      }

}
```

Comment: Thats fine..but is there any other solution if i dont wish to change model class

Comment: Yes you could by changing this line 
templist.add(ChatRoomModel.fromMap(x.data() as Map<String,dynamic>));
to this line :
templist.add(ChatRoomModel.fromMap(x.data() as Map<String,String>));

but if you have any variable that is not String it might cause error .